# Does anyone know what happened to moorstation.org? the 90s type foundry

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces, font-design, opentype

Does anyone know what the status is of [moorstation.org](http://moorstation.org/typoasis)'s type collection? There were probably hundreds of typefaces designed in the 90s on that site. It's been down for at least a month (HTTP Error 503).

I'm hoping this is only temporary.

Answer (score 1):

The Wayback machine shows a recent capture (June 23rd):
https://web.archive.org/web/20170623021022/http://moorstation.org:80/typoasis/typoasis1.htm

And the domain hasnt expired yet: https://www.whois.com/whois/moorstation.org

So probably temporary.

You could try emailing them: cybapee@joice.net

Comment: On the other hand, considering that the last update was about 13 years ago, perhaps they simply don't really bother doing anything about the site and haven't even noticed something's gone wrong…

Answer (score 1):

I still keep a complete copy of the typOasis website. The copy contains all the html pages, ZIPed fonts, articles, Koch's memorial, fontenium, etc. as in the lately closed online website. This is a 522Mb compressed *.zip file. If someone will like to get it, I will upload to share. Preferably, if someone would volunteer to host the website on his/her own website. Feel free to write on my email, please.

Comment: That sounds really great, but would the full original content not be protected by copyright?

Comment: No idea. Frankly speaking, I do not care...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Luc Devroye](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-91325.html), Typoasis/Moorstation shut down in July of 2017. Fortunately, Prof. Devroye hosts the fonts of [Manfred Klein](http://luc.devroye.org/klein.html) and [others](http://luc.devroye.org/fonthosting.html).